# How to prove the parameterization of Möbius strip is injective？

Tags: differential-geometry

Here I'm using the following parameterization:
$$
X(u, v)=\left(\left(2-v \sin \frac{u}{2}\right) \sin u,\left(2-v \sin \frac{u}{2}\right) \cos u, v \cos \frac{u}{2}\right),u\in(0,2\pi),v\in(-1,1).
$$

I want to prove this parameterization is injective but I cannot prove this by just calculating the formula.

Any help will be thanked.

Comment: @CiaPan I take u$\in (0,2\pi)$ so it's still injective.

Comment: OK, I must have misunderstood what I wanted to say. Deleted my comment.

Comment: If you restrict each of $u,v$ to *open* intervals, you need to check if your map gives a complete Mobius strip. That is, does it connect back to itself in a loop? [otherwise it's not a strip but just a rectangle.]

Comment: @coffeemath Yes I know I need another map to cover all the strip.I just want to show this one is injective.

Comment: @Tree23 I see. probably someone can do this, but if I see no response I'll have a try.

Comment: @Tree23 Since no one posted about this I included an answer showing one to one.

Comment: @Tree23 Just noticed my answer omitted an equation, now fixed.

Comment: @Tree23 Sorry your note was right I need to work more on it. Deleted for now, maybe someone else will show it.

Comment: @coffeemath It's ok,thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be easily seen by factoring the parametrization. Here's a detailed sketch.

First consider the mapping
$$
\Phi(R, \theta, \phi) = ((2 - R\cos\tfrac{1}{2}\phi)\cos\theta, (2 - R\cos\tfrac{1}{2}\phi)\sin\theta, R\sin\tfrac{1}{2}\phi),
$$
which sends the coordinate box $-1 < R < 1$, $0 < \theta < 2\pi$, and $0 < \phi < 2\pi$ onto an open dense portion of a solid torus with major radius $2$ and minor radius $1$. We claim $\Phi$ is injective in this domain.

Since $r := 2 - R\cos\tfrac{1}{2}\phi > 0$ for $-1 < R < 1$, the mapping $\Phi$ send each slice $\theta = \text{constant}$ into the longitudinal half-plane $r > 0$ at angle $\theta$ in cylindrical coordinates. Consequently, if $\Phi(R, \theta, \phi) = \Phi(R', \theta', \phi')$, then $\theta = \theta'$. Now, comparing components gives
$$
R\cos\tfrac{1}{2}\phi = R'\cos\tfrac{1}{2}\phi',\qquad
R\sin\tfrac{1}{2}\phi = R'\sin\tfrac{1}{2}\phi'.
$$
Squaring and adding shows $R^{2} = R'^{2}$, or $R = \pm R'$. Since $(\cos\frac{1}{2}\phi, \sin\frac{1}{2}\phi)$ traces the upper open half-circle for $0 < \phi < 2\pi$, the preceding equations show $R = R'$, and then $\phi = \phi'$.

It follows that $X(u, v) = \Phi(v, u, u)$ is a composition of injective mappings.

---

Given this viewpoint, it may actually be easier to write the proof without factoring the parametrization, but the cylindrical coordinates interpretation should help organize the details.